# Magento 2: Custom Instructions of Robots.txt is not working

Tags: magento2, robots.txt

We are facing an issue and need your guidance to solve that. The issue is that we have updated the custom instructions for robots.txt file as below

```
User-agent:*
Disallow:
```

But in the frontend, its showing as below

```
User-agent:*
Disallow: /
```

I have cleared and flushed the cache. So what could be the issue?

Any help will be appreciated!